# Bash script error: [i: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

This program is suppose to accept a number from the user and print that many prime numbers. For some reason the program doesn't work. I am new to bash scripting and this is my first program. To my eyes everything seems to be correct. Please tell me where I went wrong.

```
echo Enter num
read n
i=2
j=2

for(( i=2; i <= n; i++ ))
do

for(( j=2; j < i-1; j++ ))
do

if [i % j == 0];
then
break
fi


if [i == j];
then
echo "  $i"
fi
done
done
```

This is the output I get

```
Enter num
20
prime.sh: line 12: [i: command not found
prime.sh: line 18: [i: command not found
prime.sh: line 12: [i: command not found
prime.sh: line 18: [i: command not found
 .
 .
 .
```

After making the suggested changes

```
read -p "Enter a  number : " n
i=2
j=2
for(( i=2; i <= n; i++ ))
do
    for(( j=2; j <= i-1; j++ ))
    do
        if [ $(( i % j )) == 0 ]
        then
            break
        fi
        if [ i == j ]
        then
            echo "  $i"
        fi
    done
done
```

I was able to run the program but it didn't produce any result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd1se.png

Comment: Bash is very whitespace-sensitive. In this case, you want to replace `[i % j == 0]` with `[ i % j == 0 ]`.

Comment: I changed `if [i % j == 0]` and `if [i == j]`  to `if [ i % j == 0 ]` and `if [ i == j ]`. Now it says Line 11: Too many arguments. Line 11 is `if [ i % j == 0 ]`

Comment: Also, you need to add the `$` symbol when reading variables. Silly me. :P

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Does that include the variables in for loop ?

Comment: `j` only runs from 2 to `i`-1. It will never equal `i`.

Comment: In Bash, you should do integer comparisons inside `(())`, so for example: `if (( i % j == 0 )); then` and `if (( i == j )); then`. Dollar signs aren't needed in this case. Also, you need to indent your code. When you do other tests (non-integer) in Bash, you should use double square brackets `if [[ $string1 == $string2 ]]` rather than single ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place a space after the `[` because `[` is an application.

And you can't make calculations between the brackets. You will need to tell bash it needs to calculate the values. So you would need to change line 11 to `if (( i % j == 0 ))`.

Comment: what about the second if condtion ?

Comment: The second if is not an calculation however the `==` is a bash comperator and using `-eq` is more common which will make `if [ $i -eq $j ]`

Comment: @DipSwitch: i == j **is** a calculation. if `(( i % j == 0 ))` would do it.

Comment: The application `[` / `test` supports = and == as arguments so you won't need to make that a calculation and `if [ $i == $j ]; then ..; fi;` would suffice. For the modulo calculation part... I corrected that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`if [i % j == 0];` Should be `if [ i % j == 0 ];`

Same for the one on line 18

Comment: should I add a $ sign `if [ $i % $j == 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, the `[` program needs a space before its parameters, like all programs need a space before their args. This is one reason why I prefer the `test` builtin to `[` with its kludgy syntax requiring a useless `]` as the last arg just to make it look pretty and sane.

```
if test $((i % j)) = 0; then
   break
fi
```

Comment: No, a utility (which many shells provide as a built-in). But on many Unices you will find `/bin/test` or `/usr/bin/test` (which are usually hard links to `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[`). The differnce is that `[` requires `]` as the last argument so the syntax looks sane (it serves no other purpose).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# primes
#
read -p "Enter a  number: " n
i=2

for (( i=2; i <= n; i++ ))
do
    for (( j=2; j*j < i; j++ ))
    do
        if ((i % j == 0))
        then
            echo "no prime, $i divider: "$j
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

#### updated, after realizing (thanks Will Ness), that all primes up to INPUT are searched.

i needs to run to √(n) only.

Comment: the OP obviously tries to print out all primes below a given number, hence the two loops. :)